# Is there a python 3d topographical plot that works with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bokeh

I am processing x, y, and z data to have a floor map with high and lows. Z being a displacement sensor. I need to plot a topographical map with gradients. I currently have a 3D scatter plot and a contour plot using matplotlib widgets. Those work great, but a wireframe map or topgraphical map would work best. Either 2D or 3D work as well. Thank you in advance!

Current outputs:

[3D Scatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y93hF.png)

[3D Contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SsRy.png)

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

[Bokeh surface 3D plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPlqz.png)

[2D plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XILdr.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')
%matplotlib widget
%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib nbagg
%matplotlib ipympl
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')


#Extend width of Jupyter Notebook
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))

#Read CSV
df = pd.read_csv('Floor Scan.csv')
clean_df = df.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any')
print(clean_df)
print('')

z_offset = (clean_df['Displacement (in)'].min())
z_offset_abs = abs(z_offset)
print("Minimum Z:" + str(z_offset))

#3D SCATTER

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = clean_df['fActualPosition_X (-)']
y = clean_df['fActualPosition_Y (-)']
z = clean_df['Displacement (in)']

ax.scatter(x, y, (z + z_offset_abs), c='b', marker='^')
plt.xlabel("fActualPosition_X (-)")
plt.ylabel("fActualPosition_Y (-)")

plt.show()
plt.savefig('Floor_Map_Scatter_3D.svg')

#3D CONTOUR

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X = clean_df['fActualPosition_X (-)'].astype(np.uint8)
Y = clean_df['fActualPosition_Y (-)'].astype(np.uint8)
Z = clean_df['Displacement (in)'].astype(np.uint8)

flatX = np.asarray(clean_df['fActualPosition_X (-)'])
flatY = np.asarray(clean_df['fActualPosition_Y (-)'])
flatZ = np.asarray(clean_df['Displacement (in)'])

# flatX, flatY = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
# flatZ = function(flatX, flatY, Z)

# print(flatX)
# print('')
# print(flatY)
# print('')
# print(flatZ)
# print('')

plt.tricontourf(flatX, flatY, (flatZ+z_offset_abs),20)
plt.show();
plt.savefig('Floor_Map_Contour_3D.svg')
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could paste an image of the type of plot you'd like to see, along with the output from what you are currently getting. Note that you can use `hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib', width=100)` instead of the display command, to get a width of 100%, but I guess since that code doesn't actually rely on holoviews you may not want that.

Comment: Thank you James. Sorry about that. I just added the current outputs and what I am looking for. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your original data is in the form of isolated points (from a range-measuring device like LIDAR?), and what you want is not simply to plot those points, but first to infer or interpolate a surface from those points and *then* plot that surface. The two desired examples both take an already calculated grid of values and plot them either as a surface or as an image, so first you need to make such a grid, which is not strictly a plotting problem but one of data processing.

One typical way of creating the grid is to aggregate the values into Cartesian coordinates, basically just counting the average value of the scatter points per grid cell. Another is to connect up all the points into a triangular mesh, which may or may not actually form a surface (a function mapping from x,y -> z).

You can use our library [Datashader](https://datashader.org) to aggregate just about any set of data into a regular grid, and can then display it as images or contours using hvPlot (https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Gridded_Data.html) or as a surface or wireframe using HoloViews (http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/plotly/Surface.html#elements-plotly-gallery-surface).

If you want an unstructured grid, you can use scipy.spatial to compute a triangulation, then HoloViews to visualize it (http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/TriMesh.html#elements-bokeh-gallery-trimesh).